# How to add tooltip to kendo TextBlock control of kendo diagram

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am using kendo "diagram" control in my project to create sequence diagram. I am adding "textblock" control of kendo "diagram" to show some text.

however I want to show wrapped text value in "textblock" but it is not supported by kendo.

Please suggest me, if there is a way to support wrap text in "textblock" or any other alternate control of "diagram" that support same functionality of "textblock"

Thanks
Vipul

Answer (score 0):

```
function visualTemplate(options) {
    var diagram = kendo.dataviz.diagram;
    var dataItem = options.dataItem;
    var group = new diagram.Group();

    group.append(new diagram.Rectangle({
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      stroke: {
        width: 0
      },
      fill: "#e8eff7"
    }));

    group.append(new diagram.Rectangle({
      width: 8,
      height: 200,
      fill: "#3399cc",
      stroke: {
        width: 0
      }
    }));

    var layout = new diagram.Layout(new diagram.Rect(15, 0, 280, 200), {
      alignContent: "center",
      spacing: 4
    });

    group.append(layout);

    var texts = dataItem.text.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      layout.append(new diagram.TextBlock({
        text: texts[i]
      }));
    }
    layout.reflow();

    return group;
  }
```

from release 2015.3